# Debouncing a function not working - REACT functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to React so as part of learning I am trying to do a js debounce function when typed in input box (a search box simulation). But for some reason it is not working. The function is getting called each for key up than once for 2000 ms or delay specified in timeout. Below is the link to sandbox code for your reference. I have referred across blogs, the implementations seems the same yet I could not figure out what is the issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-debouncing-9g7tc?file=/src/search.component.js

Comment: With codesandbox , Please also post some related code in question and try to explain with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue :**

```
const debounce = (func, delay) => {
    let t; // <-- this will be new variable each time function get called
    return function() {
      clearTimeout(t); // <--- this also points to the new one, so it will clear nothing
      // so all the previously called func will be called
      t = setTimeout(() => func(), delay); 
    };
};
```

---

**1st Solution : useRef**

```
const t = useRef(null);

const debounce = (func, delay) => {
    return function() {
        clearTimeout(t.current); // <--- pointing to prev setTimeout or null
        t.current = setTimeout(() => func(), delay);
    };
};
```

**WORKING DEMO**

[image: Edit react-debouncing-solved]

**2nd Solution : Define `t` outside scope of `SearchUi`**

```
var t;
const SearchUi = () => {
    ...

    const debounce = (func, delay) => {
        return function() {
            clearTimeout(t);
            t = setTimeout(() => func(), delay);
        };
    };

    ...
};
```

**WORKING DEMO**

[image: Edit react-debouncing-solved2]